# ExoPlayer :extension-av1:generateJsonModelDebug breaks with NullPointer when building on GitHub actions

Tags: android, gradle, github-actions, exoplayer

I am trying to build exoplayer extensions on github .... and it fails with a NullPointerException ....

Any idea what's wrong?

THX

```
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6537198Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.083+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6539428Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.089+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6541819Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.089+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6543986Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.089+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6546287Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.089+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':extension-av1:generateJsonModelDebug'.
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6548840Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.089+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6554310Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.089+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6556863Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.089+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6558948Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.090+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6561131Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.091+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6563687Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.091+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6566871Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.092+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':extension-av1:generateJsonModelDebug'.
2021-09-28T13:28:03.6571502Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.092+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$3(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)

.....

[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-09-28T13:28:03.7414684Z 2021-09-28T13:27:56.122+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 0):

GitHub virtual env ubuntu 20.04 comes with cmake 4.21.x which is not compatible with Android SDK.

Workaround:
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/cmake

:see_no_evil:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).